# Unable to find arquillian.xml in my arquiliian project

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I want to set jboss configuration in arquillian.xml but I am unablet to find it.
Where can I find it? and if its not exist then on which path should I create it

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The file was missing. I wrote it and issue is solved